# return only distinct values from str.findall using python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to return only unique results in Python using str.findall to limit the null results eg:

```
df['A'].str.findall('Dog')

returns
    2           [Dog]
    3             []
    4             []
    5             []
    6           [Dogs]
    7             []

looking for 
    [Dog]
    [Dogs]
    []
```

Comment: Add `.unique()` to the end?

Comment: hi there.  doing so returns TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: That shouldn't happen if you're using `.str`